# Always open EntityManager

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I have fount this question, [Keeping JPA EntityManager open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393186/keeping-jpa-entitymanager-open), but I still have some concerns.

Is it good idea to have always open EnityManager during application life? Does it consume some resources like database connection? Does it keep entities or it will release them if it uses Weak references? I use EclipseLink 2.x.

Thanks

Zlaja

Answer (score 3):

EntityManager was designed to be rather short-lived. It is technically possible to keep it open for a long time, but sooner or later you will face the following issues:

1. As you wrote `EnityManager` **keeps loaded entities** and indeed it keeps them using weak references (at least with Hibernate, but I'm not sure if this is required by JPA specs). So they should be freed before JVM runs out of memory. Unfortunately, I've seen that keeping large number of entities affects EM performance **a lot** (negatively of course) when the number grows.
2. Open EM may **consume a database connection**, eg. when there are lazy-loadable objects in memory.
3. EM by definition **is not thread-safe**, so in web applications (for instance) reusing/sharing one instance is totally unacceptable.
4. Probably the biggest problem is that when there is any **error** occurring in EM (eg. on transaction commit due to violation of DB constraints), **JPA requires that EM should be closed ASAP** and discarded. This will put all your entities residing in memory to detached state, meaning that touching any lazily-loaded collections/references will fail. A workaround for that is to reload all entities, but it's difficult in bigger applications when they are scattered all over the application layers. A solution to that is to start working with detached entities and use `EntityManager.merge()`. But this usually requires changing programming model, and, in particular, is kind of contradictory to "always-open" entity manager approach. You should use only one approach and stick to it.

So generally it's better to keep `EntityManager` short-lived, it really simplifies a lot things.

Comment: #1 is true for EclipseLink, and can be configured using ReferenceMode http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/config/ReferenceMode.html

Comment: I miss read #4 - it is not true for EclipseLink, which allows triggering lazy relationships as long as the context is still available.  It would only be unavailable if the entity is serialized or if the factory is closed.